# Bootstrap Carousel - Make caption responsive to window height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've got a Bootstrap carousel implemented on my page and for some reason I cannot get the caption text to re-position according to the size of the web browser.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- =======================CAROUSEL=========================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="img/main-banner.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Democratizing the Internet of Things!</h1>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="./index.php?d=splash" role="button">Try Splash</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="img/banner-2.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another Heading!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap CDN:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

These are all my CSS changes I've made to the carousel:

```
.carousel-caption {
position: relative !important;
width: 550px;
top: 210px;
left: 380px !important;
z-index: 600;
max-height:177px;

}
.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 44px !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    line-height:36px !important;    
    color: #444 !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #fff !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
    margin-top: 11px !important;
    font-size:18px !important;
    line-height:21px !important;
    color:#333 !important;
    padding-bottom: 11px !important;
    margin-bottom: 11px !important;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #fff !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none !important;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    left: 405px !important;
}
```

This is what the carousel looks at full screen:
[image]

And here's what happens as I start to change the size of the web browser:
[image]

I have tried all the different type of positions, but for the life of me cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To vertically align the caption in the center I used the CSS function `translateY` or property `transform`.

I also wanted the caption to be placed directly beside the left carousel control.

I also removed extra bottom space that was added by the default bootstrap CSS.

```
.carousel-caption {
width: 550px;
left: 15%;
top: 50% !important;
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: left;
bottom: initial;
}
```

The caption now appears properly regardless of the screen size:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I do the carrousel responsive using

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  specific size style
}

And add my style for that size, I use tree different sizes for get all align for any screen size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That technically works but I have a 30" monitor  and I find that I have to do many different sizes. I was wondering if there is a way to simply center it 25% from the top and 25% from the left of the parent div? I tried using left,top: 25% and it resulted in the same as above

Comment: you can try with text-align:center; sometimes it works